# Remove password from password protected PDF in frontend without relying on heavy dependencies

Tags: encryption, frontend, password-protection, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I am dealing with uploads of PDF files with password protection. Instead of sending the password-protected file with the password to the backend where the file eventually can be decrypted, I want to remove the password in the frontend already, and then send the unlocked pdf as blob to the backend.

There are tools to remove a password from a pdf i.e. [node-qpdf2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qpdf2) and [ghostscript-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghostscript-js), but
I am explicitly looking for a lightweight approach without relying on depnedency-heavy tools like the mentioned above do.

When a password-protected PDF-file gets uploaded, the user is requested to provide the correct password.

I am using next.js in frontend and [pdfjs-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist) for the password prompt.

Is there any approach that I can use to decrypt the protected file in frontend? Is it possible to use pdjsLib for decryption ?

Thanks.

```
 pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';

    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(fileURL);
    
     loadingTask.onPassword = function(updatePassword:Function , reason:any) { 
      switch (reason) {
        case pdfjsLib.PasswordResponses.NEED_PASSWORD: {
          const password = prompt('Enter the password to open this PDF file.');
          setpdfPassword(password)
          updatePassword(password);
          break;
        }
        case pdfjsLib.PasswordResponses.INCORRECT_PASSWORD: {
          const password = prompt('Invalid password. Please try again.');
          setpdfPassword(password)
          updatePassword(password);
          break;
        }
      }
    };
    loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdfDocument) {
      console.log(pdfDocument)
//       PDFDocumentProxy
//        _pdfInfo:
//          {numPages: 1, fingerprints: Array(2)}
//        _transport: WorkerTransport
//          commonObjs:  PDFObjects {#ensureObj: ƒ, #objs: {…}}
//        destroyCapability: null

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fromMemory`, then `decryptPdf` or `decryptPdfOwner`, then `toMemory` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/coherentpdf

It's about 1.3Mb of client-side JS, or less if served gzipped.

Equally, the same library can do it on the server side, if your server code is in JS too.